# Excel: Search within Hyperlink Address

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that has hundreds of links to other files and folders on a network share.  The share was recently re-organized and I need to update my links.

I was hoping to do a 'find and replace', but the search in excel does not seem to find text that occurs with the hyperlink text.  So, when I search for say `\\servername\`, no results are returned, although this does appear in the hyperlink address:
[image]

[image: Excel Search Dialog]

I tried all possible settings for the 'Look in:' (formulas, values, comments)

**Is there a way to Find and Replace part of the `Address` in a hyperlink?**

Note: I'm not using the `hyperlink()` function. I've simply entered text into a cell and used Ctrl+k to assign the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an in-excel solution for this.  The availability of 3<sup>rd</sup> party solutions such as Office Add-ins [Advanced Find & Replace](https://www.office-addins.com/-excel-addins/advanced-excel-find-replace.php)  seem to confirm this.

However, there is a trick which has worked for me before.

- Save the file as `XML Spreadsheet 2003 (*.xml)`.
- Open the file in (say) Notepad++
- Perform your find & replace within Notepad++
- Save the file
- Open it again in Excel.

If you haven't made any other changes, it **should** open correctly in excel complete with any changes you made from Notepad++

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion..! It seems like it will work, I'll give it a try and report back.. :-)

Comment: This solution does allow me do a 'find and replace' on the hyperlink address, but saving to the XML Spreadsheet 2003 format causes certain aspects of my formatting to be lost, creating a different problem for me.  Even though I can't use this solution, it does allow me to achieve the stated objective, so I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: At least I now have a way to at least 'find' the cells with the text I need to update. :-)  Thanks!

Comment: You may be able to use this solution if, say, all the hyperlink cells are in the same column.  Just copy that column to a new sheet, save the new sheet in the XML Spreadsheet format, do the Find/Replace and when you reopen it in excel, that column **should** have kept its formatting so you can just copy the column back.  Of course if the hyperlinks are strewn all about the spreadsheet, or if the hyperlink text contains the formatting that gets lost this won't work

Comment: Good point..!  That may work then.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim hLink As Hyperlink

      For Each hLink In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
            hLink.Address = Replace(hLink.Address, "\\servername\", _
                    "\\NEW servername\") 

      Next hLink
    MsgBox "done - hyperlink addresses corrected"
```